# Flutter Bloc Cubit Navigator Problem BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc/Cubit of type CityCubit

Tags: flutter, bloc, cubit

I use Bloc (Cubit) for data management in my Flutter project. I get the following error in navigation operations.

> BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a
> Bloc/Cubit of type CityCubit.
> No ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to BlocProvider.of().

When I go to my city list page from the login form, I get the above error. **The error goes away when I refresh the project.** Cities are listed. However, when I log in again and redirect me, I get an error.

main.dart --> MultiBlocProvider[providers: BlocProvider, BlocProvider]

With the help of the button "BlocProvider.of  (context) .signIn (user);" logging in.

AutPage

```
BlocConsumer<AuthCubit, AuthState>(builder: (context, state) {
              return _buildUI();
            }, listener: (context, state) {
              if (state is AuthLoading) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
              if (state is AuthLoaded) {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CityListPage()));
              }
              if (state is AuthError) {
                Scaffold.of(context)
                    .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(state.message)));
                print(state.message);
              }
            })
```

CityListPage

```
List<CityModel> cities = [];        
@override
          void initState() {
            BlocProvider.of<CityCubit>(context).getAll();
            super.initState();
          }
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Hello"),
            ),
            body: BlocConsumer<CityCubit, CityState>(builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is CityInitial) {
                return Text("....");
              }
              if (state is CityLoading) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
              if (state is CitiesLoaded) {
                cities.addAll(state.cities);
              }
              return _buildCities();
            }, listener: (context, state) {
              if (state is CityError) {
                print("Error");
              }
            }));
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (state is AuthLoaded) {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CityListPage()));
              }
```

Here use BlocProvider or BlocProvider.value

Something Like Below,

```
if (state is AuthLoaded) {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => CityCubit(),
            child: CityListPage(),
          )));
                  }
```